# Number of Ethereum transactions per day since 2015

Tags: ethereum-classic

I have plotted the number of Ethereum transactions since 30th August 2015 (around inception). This is how the graph looks like. I expected a trend in which the number of transactions in a day will be lesser in 2016,17 and more in 2021,22. But it shows almost a linear trend with occasional dips in between. Why does the no. of Ethereum transactions in a day vary between 5000-6000 units at a constant pace when it should be more towards 2021,2022? Is my outcome correct? Are there these many Ethereum transactions per day in an Ethereum network?

[image]

Comment: The plot looks strange. Where are you getting the data from? This is etherscan daily transactions chart https://etherscan.io/chart/tx. It doesn't look alike. The occasional dips look like the "ice age" drops. It looks more like the daily blocks chart https://etherscan.io/chart/blocks.